# Fantasy book about Librarian mages using Bibliomancy to pull fictional items into reality for use

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

Trying to find a series I read in the library...

The story is about bibliomancy, a kind of magic where people draw on the power of mass imagination from readers of books, to retrieve fictional items from books and draw them into existence in our reality. The more readers, the greater the belief in the items and the more solid or powerful it is when brought out.

The first book in the series begins with one of the magical librarians (the protagonist) who got fired from the magic organization trying to avoid an assassination attempt by vampires I think. He got saved by a Drayad who in later books becomes his girlfriend? The dryad apparently originates from a erotic novel, i've forgotten the full title ' the nymphs of' something? She was pulled over to this universe as an acorn from the story, and thus actually is not a fictional creation but a being in this reality. Apparently if living beings are pulled into our reality they go mad.

The main character has a pet fire tarantula - a spider on fire...His pet spider isn't fully crazed because it's fictional trait of immense loyalty gives it a purpose to focus on - protecting it's owner, the protagonist.

The series reveals that the head and founder of the organization is the inventor of the printing press - Johannes Gutenberg? He's immortal apparently and invented the techniques the librarians use to retrieve objects.

The final book/s in the series main plot is about the attempt of a chinese group of librarians who are trying to retrieve their leader who wrote herself into a book centuries ago. They claim the librarians attacked them for their ability to perform their own bibliomancy? So they hate the organization. There was something about using metal sentient bugs controlled by a queen bug, invented by a character that was the protagonist's friend but who got killed earlier on? This person's father is allied to the chinese group and is using them...

Please help me to find this series! Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Magic Ex Libris series by Jim Hines. The third book comes out next year

**Magic ex Libris**

1. **Libriomancer** (2012)
   Isaac Vainio is a Libriomancer, a member of the secret organization founded five centuries ago by Johannes Gutenberg. Libriomancers are gifted with the ability to magically reach into books and draw forth objects. When Isaac is attacked by vampires that leaked from the pages of books into our world, he barely manages to escape. To his horror he discovers that vampires have been attacking other magic-users as well, and Gutenberg has been kidnapped.
   With the help of a motorcycle-riding dryad who packs a pair of oak cudgels, Isaac finds himself hunting the unknown dark power that has been manipulating humans and vampires alike. And his search will uncover dangerous secrets about Libriomancy, Gutenberg, and the history of magic. . . .
2. **Codex Born** (2013)
3. **Unbound** (2015)

Comment: Is this any good?

Comment: Thanks Dai!

bmargulies I read it some time ago and I was speed reading, I finished all three in 1 day so my memory of the writing isn't as defined but I did enjoy the plot. I think I did find some bits of the story a bit clumsy, but not overall. The concept was really interesting as well and the characters were quite well developed. I would recommend reading it!